# AWK: Divide any element of any row by some element of another row

Tags: awk

I have got a text file with some structure like this:

```
2 2 4 5 6
1 9 7 6 2
1 5 2 8 5
```

I want to be able to divide any element of any row by an element of another row. For example if I wanted to divide the 3rd element of the 1st row by the 2nd element of the 3rd row that would give:

```
4/5 = 0.8
```

Couldn't figure out a smart way to do this with AWK. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MAY be what you want but it's hard to tell without more details and the expected output:

```
$ awk -v num=1,5 -v den=3,3 '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) cell[NR","i]=$i} END{print (cell[den] ? cell[num]/cell[den] : "NaN")}' file
3

$ awk -v num=3,4 -v den=1,2 '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) cell[NR","i]=$i} END{print (cell[den] ? cell[num]/cell[den] : 0)}' file
4
```

Answer (score 0):

If (i1, j1) and (i2, j2) are the coordinates of the numerator and the denominator, you can do this :

```
i1=1
j1=3
i2=3
j2=2

awk 'NR=='$i1'{a=$'$j1'} NR=='$i2' {b=$'$j2'} END {print a"/"b " = " a/b}' file
```

Comment: Never let shell variables expand into the body of an awk script like that. google it if you don't know why and then see how to really pass the values of shell variables to awk scripts at: http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24. Also consider what would happen if the value of `b` is zero.